# Conditional HTML to target ie8 quirks mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, quirks-mode

I have a page that's not displaying correctly in ie8 quirks mode. If I want to create some CSS to target just that mode, but not ie8 normally, what would be the conditional HTML?

For example, if I wanted to just hit ie8:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    awesome hacky stuff goes here
<![endif]-->
```

So what is the `IE 8` part for ie8 quirks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use conditional comments to target a browser's rendering mode (just versions).

If you are in quirks mode, use a [doc type](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) that doesn't invoke it.

**Unless**, you are referring to IE8's compatibility mode, which makes the browser render similar to IE7. In that case, use the following conditional comment...

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    awesome hacky stuff goes here
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to test for quirks mode. Instead, use a DOCTYPE and make sure your HTML validates to it. XHTML DOCTYPEs are probably better.

Comment: Going for `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Thanks!

Comment: Any strict doctype as well as the HTML5 doctype works, actually.

Comment: I don't know how well <!DOCTYPE html> (which is the HTML5 doctype) will work with IE8, given that it doesn't support HTML5, but it's worth a try. It's also the best doctype for forwards compatibility.

Comment: it doesn't appear to change how ie8 in quirks mode renders, actually.

Comment: Try the HTML4.01 or XHTML 1.0 Transitional DOCTYPES. IE supports those. Also, be sure your (X)HTML validates to it's doctype. Try here ---> http://validator.w3.org/